# C WinAPI and C++ MFC resource

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, mfc

I would like to ask you guys if you know what are the best(comprehensive) books for the following topics:

C Win32/WinAPI programming;
Book or Catalog of windows functions in windows.h and all the other windows library for c;
Book or Catalog of standard C library;

C++ MFC books;

I did my homework, but google does not certify nor guarantee professional answers, i hope Stack Overflow does.

thank you.

Comment: "If you want guarantees, buy a toaster." --Clint Eastwood.
If you just want a good answer, this has been asked several times. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426782/win32-api-programming-book

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Petzold for learning the raw windows API

[http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ISBN=157231995X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/157231995X)

This will give you a good foundation for groking how things work under the hood.  This is important because MFC is essentially a wrapper and and sometimes you have to get lower level.  You'll be a much stronger developer if you don't depend on the IDE and wizards for everything.  Petzold strongly emphasizes this.

Prosise is good for MFC:

[http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Windows-MFC-Second-Edition/dp/1572316950](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1572316950)